# How do I control what JRE version is bundled with my application?

Tags: java, launch4j

I'm considering bundling a JRE with my Java application. I'm using Launch4J. Looking around stackoverflow this seems easy enough to do. What I've not seen any information on is where I get the JRE from in a controlled manner.

I'd like to be able to control from a single place what version of the JRE is bundled. I don't want to be manually updating/installing JRE's on n number of build machines each time we decided to use a different JRE. Placing the JRE under source control seems the most logical option. Our build is done using maven, I assumed there would be some kind of maven plugin that would download a configured JRE version and put it in the target folder for you.

So, what is best practice to control which JRE is bundled with my app?

Answer (score 0):

check the  Maven enforcer plugin http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/ and in that check for  requireJavaVersion http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireJavaVersion.html . this will  add checks to the build that fail when the inapproriate  JRE is used.